# Image resize and crop. Problems with box movement on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a image editor tool to go with my image uploader system. I got most of it working, but I think the box with the image and the box for cropping moves kind of weird on resizing. Especially when trying to resize from left bottom corner and both top corners.

I don't really know if this is a `CSS` issue or some problems with the `jQuery` logic. I would really appreciate if someone could take a look.

I know `jQuery UI` have `draggable, resizable` etc but, I wanted to make this my self.

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3g7zfvdo/30/)

**EDIT:** I got it working alot better when changing from `resize.width()` and `resize.hight()` to my variables `width` and `height` but the movment is still kinda weird when resizing from left to right. (jsfiddle updated)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var dragging = null;
    var resize = null;
    var pos;
    var height;
    var width;

    $(".image-resize__box").on("mousemove", function (e) {
        if (dragging) {
            dragging.offset({
                top: e.pageY,
                left: e.pageX
            });
        }
    });

    $(".image-resize__box__crop__box").on("mousedown", null, function () {
        dragging = $(".image-resize__box__crop");
    });

    $(".image-resize__box__handle").on("mousedown", null, function () {
        resize = $(".image-resize__box");
        pos = $(this).attr("data-pos");
        height = resize.height();
        width = resize.width();
    }); 

    $(document.body).on("mousemove", null, function (e) {

        if (resize) {

            var relX = e.pageX - resize.offset().left;
            var relY = e.pageY - resize.offset().top;

            if(pos === "top-left") {
                resize.css({ 
                    "width" : resize.width() - relX,
                    "height" : resize.height() - relY, 
                });
            }
            if(pos === "top-mid") {
                resize.css({ 
                    "width" : width,
                    "height" : height - relY, 
                });
            }
            if(pos === "top-right") {
                resize.css({ 
                    "width" : resize.width() + (relX - resize.width()),
                    "height" : resize.height() - relY, 
                });
            }
            if(pos === "mid-right") {
                resize.css({ 
                    "width" : resize.width() + (relX - resize.width()),
                    "height" : height, 
                });
            }
            if(pos === "mid-left") {
                resize.css({ 
                    "width" : resize.width() - relX,
                    "height" : height, 
                });
            }
            if(pos === "bottom-left") {
                resize.css({ 
                    "width" : resize.width() - relX,
                    "height" : resize.height() + (relY - resize.height()), 
                });
            }
            if(pos === "bottom-mid") {
                resize.css({ 
                    "width" : width,
                    "height" : resize.height() - (resize.height() - relY), 
                });
            }
            if(pos === "bottom-right") {
                resize.css({ 
                    "width" : resize.width() + (relX - resize.width()),
                    "height" : resize.height() + (relY - resize.height()), 
                });
            }
        }
    });

    $(document.body).on("mouseup", function () {
        resize = null;
        dragging = null;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you can click somewhere *inside* the handles, but then on mouse move, you jump to the `0,0` position of the handle. This results in the image "jumping" in size.

You can fix this by factoring in the offset of the mouse click from the handle origin, and adding that to the x and y of the onmousemove event.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have gotten most of it working now. Still some small things to fix like, the crop box is currently able to move outside the image box. If anyone should be interested a updated jsfiddle can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3g7zfvdo/70/)

```
(function () {

    //-------------------------------------------------
    // Image details 
    //-------------------------------------------------

    var imageDetails = function() {

        var details = function () {

            $("#imageWidth").html($(".image-resize__box").width());
            $("#imageHeight").html($(".image-resize__box").height());
            $("#cropWidth").html($(".image-resize__box__crop").width());
            $("#cropHeight").html($(".image-resize__box__crop").height());
            $("#cropOffsetTop").html($(".image-resize__box__crop").position().top);
            $("#cropOffsetLeft").html($(".image-resize__box__crop").position().left);

        };

        return {
            getDetails: details
        };

    }();

    //-------------------------------------------------
    // Image  resizer
    //-------------------------------------------------

    var imageResize = function() {

        $(document).ready(function () {

            //-------------------------------------------------
            // Global variables
            //-------------------------------------------------

            var dragging = null;
            var resize = null;
            var pos;
            var height;
            var width;
            var crop = $(".image-resize__box__crop");
            var resizeBox = $(".image-resize__box");

            //-------------------------------------------------
            // Event handlers
            //-------------------------------------------------
            // Set dragging active on mouse down
            $(".image-resize__box__crop__box").on("mousedown", null, function () {

                dragging = crop;

            });

            // Set resize active on mouse down
            $(".image-resize__box__handle").on("mousedown", null, function () {

                // Resize crop box
                if($(this).parent().hasClass("image-resize__box__crop")) {

                    resize = crop;

                } else { // Resize image

                    resize = resizeBox;

                }

                pos = $(this).attr("data-pos"); // Resize handler used
                height = resize.height(); // Height of element resize
                width = resize.width(); // Width of element to resize

            }); 

            // Deactivate resize/dragging
            $(document.body).on("mouseup", function () {

                resize = null;
                dragging = null;

            });

            //-------------------------------------------------
            // Drag (crop box)
            //-------------------------------------------------

            resizeBox.on("mousemove", function (e) {

                if (dragging) {

                    dragging.offset({

                        top: e.pageY - (crop.height()/ 2),
                        left: e.pageX - (crop.width()/ 2),

                    });

                    imageDetails.getDetails(); // Update image details

                }
            });

            //-------------------------------------------------
            // Resize image
            //-------------------------------------------------

            $(document.body).on("mousemove", null, function (e) {

                if (resize) {

                    var relX = e.pageX - resize.offset().left; // Mouse position in element left
                    var relY = e.pageY - resize.offset().top; // Mouse position in element top

                    //-------------------------------------------------
                    // Resize handlers
                    //-------------------------------------------------

                    if(pos === "top-left") {

                        resize.css({ 
                            "width" : width - relX,
                            "height" : height - relY, 
                        });

                    }

                    if(pos === "top-mid") {
                        resize.css({ 
                            "width" : width,
                            "height" : height - relY, 
                        });
                    }

                    if(pos === "top-right") {

                        resize.css({ 
                            "width" : width + (relX - width),
                            "height" : height - relY, 
                        });

                    }

                    if(pos === "mid-right") {

                        resize.css({ 
                            "width" : width + (relX - width),
                            "height" : height, 
                        });

                    }

                    if(pos === "mid-left") {

                        resize.css({ 
                            "width" : width - relX,
                            "height" : height, 
                        });

                    }

                    if(pos === "bottom-left") {

                        resize.css({ 
                            "width" : width - relX,
                            "height" : height + (relY - height), 
                        });

                    }

                    if(pos === "bottom-mid") {
                        resize.css({ 
                            "width" : width,
                            "height" : height - (height - relY), 
                        });
                    }

                    if(pos === "bottom-right") {

                        resize.css({ 
                            "width" : width + (relX - width),
                            "height" : height + (relY - height), 
                        });

                    }

                    imageDetails.getDetails(); // Update image details

                }

            });

        });

    }(imageDetails.getDetails());

}());
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed jumping of cropbox as well as weird resizing. I added `drag` variable to keep track of previous `x` and `y` position

you can check it here [Updated Cropbox](https://jsfiddle.net/ruht5vyf/1/)